# Simple function convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Define simple function ${\chi _E}(x) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&{x \in E}\\
0&{x \notin E}
\end{array}} \right.$

How do we show ${\chi _{(\alpha_k  - \delta ,\alpha_k  + \delta )}}(x) - {\chi _{(\alpha_0  - \delta ,\alpha_0 + \delta )}}(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $\alpha_k \to \alpha_0 $, where $\alpha_k$ is a sequence converging to $\alpha_0$; $\alpha_k ,\alpha_0 ,\delta  \in \Bbb{R}$; and $(\alpha_k  - \delta ,\alpha_k  + \delta ), (\alpha_0 - \delta ,\alpha_0 + \delta )$ are just intervals.

Although it looks naive, I have trouble giving a proof. Hope someone can help. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the statement is not true. Let $a_0=0$ and $a_k=\frac{1}{k}$ and let $\delta = 1$. Consider the value of the function at the point $x=1$. Clearly 
$$\chi_{(-1,1)}(1)=0$$
but
$$\chi_{(-1+\frac{1}{k}, 1 + \frac{1}{k})}(1)=1$$
for all positive integral $k$. The difference function in this case actually converges to the function $\chi_{\{1\}}$.

<s>However, if you make your conditions a little stronger, the theorem is true. Define $\chi_E$ to be $1$ in the closure of $E$ and $0$ everywhere else, and then the theorem you state is true.</s>